# SQL subqueries fetch more rows that outer query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to figure out a way to fetch two data sets from different tables. here is a working version of the SQL

```
SELECT l.id AS teamId, l.leagueId, t.name AS teamName, a.id
FROM leagues AS l
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT a.id, a.teamId
    FROM activities AS a
    WHERE a.status=(:a) AND a.leagueId=(:l) 
        AND a.apply_standings=(:p) AND a.activityCode = (:g) 
) on a.teamId = l.teamId
JOIN teams AS t ON t.id = l.teamId
WHERE l.status !=(:s) AND l.leagueId=(:l)
ORDER BY teamId
LIMIT 55


TABLES
Teams
+-----------+-----------+
|   id      |   name    |                                                           
+-----------+-----------+
1             Scorpions
2             Jazz  
...

League
+------------+-----------+
|   leagueId |  teamId   |                                                            
+------------+-----------+
1               2
1               1
2               1
3               4
...

Activities
+-----------+----------------+---------+
|   id      |   activityCode |  teamId |                                                    
+-----------+----------------+---------+
1               game            1
2               social          2
3               ..              1
4               ..              3
...
```

The problem with this query is if there are more activities that one (which there are) the query will only return one result. I have tried to convert the above statement into  a subquery on the selected various but i hit the SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s) error.

essentially i am trying to get a results similar to this

```
array(
    "team_name",
          array(
              ..activity details
          ),
          array(
              ..activity details
          ),
          array(
              ..activity details
          ),
),
    "other Name",
          array(
              ..activity details
          ),
          array(
              ..activity details
          ),
          array(
              ..activity details
          ),
);
```

I know that this is not the format I will receive it in, but that is the best representation of it i can think of.

Comment: First, your subquery isn't being joined ONTO anything. Also, why don't you just select from activities and join the other tables onto it? Lastly, if you could set up some kind of dummy data in SQLfiddle or something, that would help us out, tremendously.

Comment: Hi,  your suggestion would make everything considerably easier if and only if every team had an activity that i could use to join. This will eventually be the case but it is not. So if i was to grab the data i would only  see partial results instead of a full list of teams --see my comment to @adam for more clarification

Comment: Oh, ok. Give me a few minutes and I'll try to parse something for you. Though, I still don't understand why your not joining your select ON anything.

Comment: Hi, sorry that was definatelly an error there was an ON statement

Comment: You still have some confusing errors in your question (I assume from reformatting). Could you please take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly, you want:

- all club_member entries that have a team_id
- only entries that match some constraints (leagueid, status, standings, activity code?)
- then to get all activities (if any) for those entries.
- all results from those activities? (not sure about this one)
- list results by teamId

Also, please excuse any syntax issues, I'm not as familiar with MySQL as I am with other SQL engines.

```
SELECT 
    cm.id AS teamId, cm.leagueId, t.name AS teamName, a.id, 
    a.homeId, a.awayId, a.score_away, a.score_home
FROM `clubs-members` AS cm
JOIN teams AS t ON t.id = cm.teamId
LEFT JOIN activities AS a ON (a.teamId = cm.teamId AND a.status=(:a) 
     AND a.apply_standings=(:p) AND a.activityCode = (:g) )
LEFT JOIN `activities-results` AS r ON r.activityId = a.id AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(r.approved) != 0
WHERE cm.status !=(:s) AND cm.leagueId=(:l)
ORDER BY teamId
LIMIT 55
```

Please let me know if this gets you to where you're trying to go.

Comment: I want 1) the listing of teams in the club_members field with all the same leagueId. In the new sql up top, the SQL table of leagues represents club members. The parameters would be leagueId equal to 1 or 8  and then the status would be activie. The second data a set i am after is all the activities for the teams within the league. I wouldnt worry too much about the other information as i can figure that our pretty easily once i grasp how to accomplish the two data sets                               the Sql didnt work instead it just got teams with acitivities and i want teams with and without

Comment: @bushbrigade It's because of your activities constraints (like a.status=(:a)). I moved that up to the join and it should work, I think (again, not 100% sure how syntax works in MySQL)

Comment: @bushbrigade Glad I could hep =D. I mostly use PL-SQL and MS-SQL Server. Also, if you want the comments to pick up the "@username", it has to be at the beginning of the comment (like mine is above)